# C,C++ CPU usage and memory usage of processes in all platforms + available network downlink bandwidth for current time

Tags: c++, windows, networking, memory, cpu-usage

I want to retrieve the CPU usage and memory usage of each process running in different platforms (at least for windows) in every interval of time (e.g. in every second like task manager).

Is there any C, C++ API for cross-platform?

I read PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX.PrivateUsage for each process. Is that the actual memory usage which is shown in task manager.

I am trying SIGAR API (http://www.hyperic.com/products/sigar). But, I have no progress, yet.

Moreover, I want to retrieve the available network downlink bankwidth for the current time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used SIGAR API which is cross-platform. 
http://www.hyperic.com/products/sigar

It doesn't have documentation for C++ but for java. So, at least you can read java documentation about what the function does.

Answer (score 0):

For CPU and Memory usage - look this thread in [MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/e62066d5-5127-40fd-a8ff-5757d5a4fc38)